# Sorting directories by last modified date/time of the same-named contained file

Tags: command-line, files, ls, sort, timestamps

Is it possible, using `grep`, `find`, etc, to sort a list of directories by the last modified date of the same-named file (e.g., `file.php`) within? For example:

```
domain1/file.php (last modified 20-Jan-2014 00:00)
domain2/file.php (last modified 22-Jan-2014 00:00)
domain3/file.php (last modified 24-Jan-2014 00:00)
domain4/file.php (last modified 23-Jan-2014 00:00)
```

Each directory has the same file name (e.g., `file.php`).

The result should be:

```
domain3/ (last modified 24-Jan-2014 00:00)
domain4/ (last modified 23-Jan-2014 00:00)
domain2/ (last modified 22-Jan-2014 00:00)
domain1/ (last modified 21-Jan-2014 00:00)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Vivian suggested, the `-t` option of `ls` tells it to sort files by modification time
(most recent first, by default; reversed if you add `-r`). 
This is most commonly used (at least in my experience) to sort the files in a directory,
but it can also be applied to a list of files on the command line. 
And wildcards (“globs”) produce a list of files on the command line. 
So, if you say

```
ls -t */file.php
```

it will list

```
domain3/file.php  domain4/file.php  domain2/file.php  domain1/file.php
```

But, it you add the `-1` (dash one) option, or pipe this into anything,
it will list them one per line.  So the command you want is

```
ls -t */file.php | sed 's|/file.php||'
```

This is an ordinary
`s/old_string/replacement_string/` substitution in `sed`,
but using `|` as the delimiter, because the *`old_string`* contains a `/`,
and with an empty *`replacement_string`*. 
(I.e., it deletes the filename and the `/` before it — `/file.php` —
from the `ls` output.) 
Of course, if you want the trailing `/` on the directory names,
just do `sed 's|file.php||'` or `sed 's/file.php//'`.

If you want, add the `-l` (lower-case L) option to `ls`
to get the long listing, including modification date/time. 
And then you may want to enhance the `sed` command
to strip out irrelevant information (like the mode, owner, and size of the file)
and, if you want, move the date/time after the directory name.

This will look into the directories that are *in* the current directory, and only them. 
(This seems to be what the question is asking for.) 
Doing a one-level scan of some other directory is a trivial variation:

```
ls -t /path/to/tld/*/file.php | sed 's|/file.php||'
```

To (recursively) search the entire directory tree under your current directory
(or some other top-level directory) is a little trickier. 
Type the command

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and then replace the asterisk (`*`) in one of the above commands with two asterisks (`**`), e.g.,

```
ls -t **/file.php | sed 's|/file.php||'
```

Comment: Hi thanks! Is it possible to make "*/file.php" go through unlimited directories until it finds file.php? "*/" just go through one right?

Comment: Right. To search the entire directory tree under your current directory (rather than looking only at the first level), type `shopt -s globstar`, and then change the command in my answer to use `**/file.php` (with two asterisks).

Comment: That would be useful as an option in the answer.

Comment: @geedoubleya: Done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is quite possible.

This will give you files which are modified in last 60 minutes:

```
$ find /domain -type f -mmin -60
```

or this will give you files which are sorted by modify time.

```
$ find /domain -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r
```

#### Edit #1

If you have file extensions like you said '.php', add this:

```
-name '*.php'
```

And I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566310/how-to-recursively-find-and-list-the-latest-modified-files-in-a-directory-with-s) you may want to see it.

#### Edit #2

Well your last edit gets things harder. But You can use `ls -t` to last modified directories and if you want to sort by time `ls -clRt` you could use it and after that you can check files but I'm not sure what you want is possible with any specific command. It's possible with a similiar script (Bash or Perl).

Comment: Hi Thanks. This doesn't give me a list of directories sorted by the last modified date of file.php does it?

Comment: Check edited message, I didn't recognize .php thing.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This does almost exactly what you want, except it leaves off the trailing / on the directory names.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name file1.php -printf '%T@ %h (last modified %Td/%Tm/%TY %Tk:%TM)\n' \
| sort -k 1n | sed 's/^[^ ]* .\///'
```

Credit where credit is due. This is adapted from [shlck's](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/826272).

Edit: All of my %A should have been %T

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- **/file.php(.om:h)
```

`.om` sorts the selected files by `mtime` and `:h` removes the trailing path component.
If you want to list `mtime`s too, you could use `zstat`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
for f (**/file.php(.om))
printf '%s %s\t%s\n' $(zstat -F '%d-%b-%Y %T' +mtime -- $f) ${f:h}
```